# Why is my animation not working

Tags: android, android-animation

This does not work and I wonder why. Nothing is showing but If I remove everything after the `// sleep` then the view is showing with animation, but of course it´s not hiding again..

Any advice would be grate. This is happening inside an adapter and suppose to popup a `TextView` saying like "Signed in as: your@gmail.com"

```
       Application.getInstance().runOnUiThreadDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Prepare the View for the animation
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.setAlpha(0.0f);
                // show view
                view.animate()
                        .translationY(view.getHeight())
                        .alpha(1.0f)
                        .setDuration(500);
                // sleep
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // hide view
                view.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .alpha(0.0f)
                        .setDuration(500)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }, 500);
```

The View

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_logged_in"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="logged in as wdkejhedwedrwdeklj"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: I dont see you are `start()`ing animation... Add `.start()` after `.setDuration(500).start();` and after the listener on the second animation

Comment: I do as you say but nothing happens.

Comment: That is a handler    ` public void runOnUiThreadDelay(final Runnable runnable, long delayMillis) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, delayMillis);
    }`

Comment: It´s working if I remove everything after the `// sleep` hmmm It´s popping up alright

Comment: wait a minute, could it be that the  `Thread.sleep(2000)` is halting the first animation, it runs asynchronous right??

Comment: no, If I remove the second animation and keep the `Thread.sleep(2000)` I do get it to work

Comment: ok I got it working in what I think is bad maybe, I removed the `Thread.sleep(2000)` and added one more `runOnUiThreadDelay` after the first animation, with a delay of 2000

Comment: If you need to delay the animation start, use `.setStartDelay(2000)`

Comment: Thanks all!, I run with this for now hopping someone will teach me why my animation is not working, and how to do it properly